# Android and Dagger 2 submodules

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-savedstate

If I'm using Dagger 2 with scoped submodules, it makes it easier not to pass parcelables between activities but if the app experiences process death and our Object graph is destroyed, how do you handle recovering from that?

The only thing I can think to do, is to sort of double up and use your scoped dependencies as well as putting enough data in the Bundle to recreate the graph. This way if you find that something that should be there is null, meaning the app was killed, use the state in the bundle to try and rebuild the graph.

Is there a better way than this? This partially negates using Dagger in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to use activities and even fragments is to use bundle so that in case of destroying its easy for them to recover. I never use Dagger as an alternative for this because its not what dagger is developed for.

yes, Dagger is for DI (dependency injection) but not for stopping android from knowing activities data. dagger is mostly use to provide data which you going to inject through constructor which you do this in the activity.

even in fragments best practice is to use a `newInstance()` method and inject your dependencies through this methods arguments and then save them in fragments bundle !!